# select not sending $_POST data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am confused as to why my select is not passing any post data to the results page. If I run var_dump($_POST); the select (#boxdest or #boxdest2) is not being displayed. Is there some special way to pass select to php results page. What I normally do is as an example: $var=$_POST['boxdest'];. Problem is the select is not being sent from original code. I have posted my code and would be grateful if someone could show me where I have gone wromg. Many thanks.

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("sample",$conn); 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM boxes where department = '{$_GET['dept']}'");
    ?>
   <select id="boxdest" name="boxdest[]"size="7">

    <?php
        $i=0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row["custref"];?>"><?php echo $row["custref"];?></option>

    <?php
        $i++;
    }

    ?>
    </select>

<input type="button" id="submit2" name="submit2" value=">" />
<input type="button" id="submit3" name="submit3" value="<" />
<select id="boxdest2" name="boxdest2[]" size="7"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#submit2").click( function()
           {
             //alert('button clicked');

     $box1_value=$("#boxdest").val();
     $box1_text=$("#boxdest option:selected").text();
     $("#boxdest2").append('<option value="'+$box1_value+'">'+$box1_text+'</option>');
            $("#boxdest option:selected").remove();


        });


    $("#submit3").click( function()
           {
             //alert('button3 clicked');
        $box2_value=$("#boxdest2").val();
     $box2_text=$("#boxdest2 option:selected").text();
     $("#boxdest").append('<option value="'+$box2_value+'">'+$box2_text+'</option>');
        $("#boxdest2 option:selected").remove();
           }
        );
</script>
```

Comment: Why not ```echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST,true)."</pre>";``` to see what is being sent to the php script?

Comment: The mysql_* functions are deprecated in PHP, so you might also like to look at the mysqli_* functions as an alternative.  To answer your actual question, try calling mysql_error() after the mysql_query as this will show you if there are errors which might explain why you have no results returned.

Comment: Where is your `<form>` ? how do you send it?

Comment: @Sloan still not showing. I see all other posts.

Comment: @Lorna The $_POST is not dependent on mysql. The data is being loaded correctly. It is the $_POST that is not passing.

Comment: @Peter I didn't post the form part but it is there.

Comment: @user1532468 can you please include it. such silly mistake like `metod="POST"` (missing `h`) can cause your issue

Comment: Do as I suggested in the php code, then post what it shows (or just look at it), you will see what is being sent for the select and any other fields in the form.

Comment: @Sloan Array
(
    [requested] => User1
    [destservice] => Destruction
    [dept] => 
    [address1] => 
    [status] => 9
    [Submit] => Next
) no boxdest

Comment: @Peter method="post" is included

Comment: @user1532468 can you show us full generated HTML code. I really believe we will be able to help then. If your PHP is not broken HTML code is wrong.

Comment: @Peter there is too much to post. However it is only this $_POST that is not being posted and I have included full code for that. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 try changing `name="boxdest[]"` to `name="boxdest"`

Comment: @Bojan No change